# Gumstix to Gumstix Communication

Tags: microcontroller, uart, serial-communication, usbserial, gumstix

I am trying to get enable communication between two Gumstix via UART or even USB. I have had issues finding any useful online resources so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

- I have two of the gumstix overo series summit with the Gumstix Firestorm attached
- The following link is for the pin map
  http://gumstix.org/hardware-design/overo-coms/74-overo-connectors/97-gumstix-overo-series-40-pin-header.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a gumstix overo, there is 3 serial ports. Usually, 1 serial port is used for the terminal / console. 1 serial is for the bluetooth (it is possible to mux the signal on the external connector) modifying u-boot package.

If both COM are near, you don't have to use a RS232 signal transceiver. Only be sure to plus RX with TX and TX with RX.

For the communication itself, you need to look at standard linux library for uart usage. The overo linux serial port is /dev/ttyO[0:2]

You can use yocto for your package management.